# In an if/else statment, when I have the "if" body toast is displayed for empty EditText BUT when I add the else body, it does not get displayed

Tags: java, android

My program is a unit converter.
I am trying to check if the user has entered a number, can be a decimal, and make it so that if the text field is empty and the user presses the `Convert` button (when the convert button is pressed the `convertUnits` method is called) a toast pops up and says "Please enter a number". It works fine when the `else` block is not a part of the method:

```
   // When the "Convert" Button is pressed...
public void convertUnits(View view) {
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText showConvertion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    // This variable is what number the user enters
    double userInput = Double.parseDouble(inputField.getText().toString().trim());

    // Radio Buttons variables on *LEFT SIDE*
    RadioButton leftMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.leftMM);

    // Radio Buttons variables on *RIGHT SIDE*
    RadioButton rightMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);


    if (inputField.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
    // Shows Error messages to user if s/he didn't put a number in the textField -- "userInput"

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Text field is empty!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        inputField.setError("Please enter a number to convert");
        return;
```

However, when I add the `else` part of the statement (in the `else` body the math is done for conversions) and run the program the `else` body executes its code fine, but if the user enters nothing in the `EditText`, the program/app crashes:

```
  // When the "Convert" Button is pressed...
public void convertUnits(View view) {
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText showConvertion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    // This variable is what number the user enters
    double userInput = Double.parseDouble(inputField.getText().toString().trim());

    // Radio Buttons variables on *LEFT SIDE*
    RadioButton leftMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.leftMM);

    // Radio Buttons variables on *RIGHT SIDE*
    RadioButton rightMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);


    if (inputField.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
    // Shows Error messages to user if s/he didn't put a number in the textField -- "userInput"

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Text field is empty!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        inputField.setError("Please enter a number to convert");
        return;

    } else {

        // The math for conversions

        // Millimeter to Millimeter
        double milToMilResult = userInput * 1;
        String milToMilString = Double.toString(milToMilResult);


        // If the user's unit is Millimeters then...
        if (leftMillimeters.isChecked()) {
            // To Millimeters
            if (rightMillimeters.isChecked()) {
              showConvertion.setText(milToMilString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Please attach the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are parsing an empty text to double
Try putting

```
double userInput = Double.parseDouble(inputField.getText().toString().trim());
```

in the if.

```
 // When the "Convert" Button is pressed...
public void convertUnits(View view) {
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText showConvertion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    // Radio Buttons variables on *LEFT SIDE*
    RadioButton leftMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.leftMM);

    // Radio Buttons variables on *RIGHT SIDE*
    RadioButton rightMillimeters = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);


    if (inputField.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
    // Shows Error messages to user if s/he didn't put a number in the textField -- "userInput"

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Text field is empty!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        inputField.setError("Please enter a number to convert");
        return;

    } else {
 // This variable is what number the user enters
    double userInput = Double.parseDouble(inputField.getText().toString().trim());

        // The math for conversions

        // Millimeter to Millimeter
        double milToMilResult = userInput * 1;
        String milToMilString = Double.toString(milToMilResult);


        // If the user's unit is Millimeters then...
        if (leftMillimeters.isChecked()) {
            // To Millimeters
            if (rightMillimeters.isChecked()) {
              showConvertion.setText(milToMilString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```